# Duplicated query with uncapitalized Laravel relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I'm experiencing a strange behavior with `Laravel 5` and a simple relationship query:
I have an `Issues` MySQL table and another `Articles` table. Every Issue can have one or more articles, so it's a plain `OneToMany` relationship.

*Issue.php*

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Issue extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['status', 'volume', 'number', 'date'];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
    }
}
```

*Article.php*

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['status', 'authors', 'bibliography', 'references', 'notes', 'topic', 'issue_id'];
    protected $with = ['Articles_contents'];

    public function Articles_contents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Articles_content');
    }

    public function issue()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Issue');
    }
}
```

(`Articles` have an another relationship with `Articles_contents`, but I don't think that this can have connections with my problem).

When I edit an issue, I want to list all the articles that are inside it. **The articles have to be sorted by a numeric field into `Articles` table, named "sort"**:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $issue = Issue::with(array(
        'Articles' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('sort', 'asc');
        }
    ))->find($id);

    $this->data['issue'] = $issue;

    return view('admin_issues_edit', $this->data);
}
```

My problem is in the view: When I do this, to list the articles:

```
        @foreach( $issue->Articles as $article )
          <li id="article_{{ $article->id }}">{!! link_to_route('admin.articles.edit', $article->Articles_contents->first()->title, array($article->id)) !!}</li>
        @endforeach
```

... I get the right, minimal, queries:

> select * from `issues` where `issues`.`id` = '8' limit 1
>
> select * from `articles` where `articles`.`issue_id` in ('8') order by `sort` asc
>
> select * from `articles_contents` where `articles_contents`.`article_id` in ('20', '14', '5')

But if I do the same thing, with lowercase `->articles`, like the documentation suggests:

```
        @foreach( $issue->articles as $article )
          <li id="article_{{ $article->id }}">{!! link_to_route('admin.articles.edit', $article->Articles_contents->first()->title, array($article->id)) !!}</li>
        @endforeach
```

I get a duplicated query, with a `is not null` statement:

> select * from `issues` where `issues`.`id` = '8' limit 1
>
> select * from `articles` where `articles`.`issue_id` in ('8') order by `sort` asc
>
> select * from `articles_contents` where `articles_contents`.`article_id` in ('20', '14', '5')
>
> select * from `articles` where `articles`.`issue_id` = '8' and `articles`.`issue_id` is not null
>
> select * from `articles_contents` where `articles_contents`.`article_id` in ('5', '14', '20')

Of course the two queries to `articles_contents` are normal because I did the automatic eager loading in the model, but I'm getting two queries to the `Articles` table: the first with the correct sorting I'm requesting, and the second one with a strange `issue_id` is not null part.

What's wrong? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because, when do this:

```
 @foreach( $issue->Articles as $article )
      <li id="article_{{ $article->id }}">{!! link_to_route('admin.articles.edit', $article->Articles_contents->first()->title, array($article->id)) !!}</li>
 @endforeach
```

You loop the already (egerly loaded) available `Articles` because you have used:

```
array(
    'Articles' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('sort', 'asc');
    }
)
```

So `Articles` is present but when you use `articles` it just loads the articles right then because there is no `articles` key available in the relations array. So that is another query gets executed at the run time and this is dynamic behavior of `Eloquent` relationships and yes `is not null` is used by `Laravel` when it executes the query.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Just a last question: is it correct to use "Articles" or "articles", in this case? I guess it's the lowercase version because it's not a class name, isn't it? :)

Comment: You are welcome @flip79. Regarding the question, use the name qof the relationship method you created in your moidel, so if that is `Article` then you should use `Article` bur use a lower case for method name and use singular name if that is one-to-one or use plural for one-to-many/many-to-many relationship.